# DJANGO NoReverseMatch at /"reverse not found"

Tags: python, django

first time with django, need some help...

Error:

```
Reverse for 'anuncio' with arguments '(u'Restaurante Avenida',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Request Method:     GET
Django Version:     1.5.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'anuncio' with arguments '(u'Restaurante Avenida',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 424
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3

url:

```
url(r'^anuncio/(?P<titulo>\d+)$', anuncio),
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url 'anuncio' user.userprofile.anuncio %}"> {{user.userprofile.anuncio}} </a>
```

view:

```
def anuncio(request, titulo):

Anuncio = Anuncio.objects.get(titulo = titulo)

variables = RequestContext(request, {'anuncio': Anuncio})

return render_to_response('anuncio.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
url(r'^anuncio/(?P<titulo>\d+)$', anuncio),
```

`\d+` matches digits.

What you need is to match alphabets and space.

Try

```
url(r'^anuncio/(?P<titulo>[\w ]+)$', anuncio, name = 'anuncio'),
```

Also, here

```
Anuncio = Anuncio.objects.get(titulo = titulo)
```

Please use a different variable name. Do **not** override the model name.

```
anuncio = Anuncio.objects.get(titulo = titulo)
```

One more thing, `.get()` will throw an error if there is no match. So, you might want to consider

```
anuncio = get_object_or_404(Anuncio, titulo = titulo)
```

Read more on [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

One last thing: Here

```
<a href="{% url 'anuncio' user.userprofile.anuncio %}"> {{user.userprofile.anuncio}} </a>
```

I would recommend using the `id`  than the `anuncio` field. Something like `user.userprofile.id` and keep the `regex` as `\d+` - Something that avoids spaces (and is unique) in the model object

Comment: I think you forget to specify the name for the url @EmanuelFaisca

Comment: Yep, got it working. Thanks again everyone!
Im really enjoying to work with django, really cool.